# Using JSON_ARRAYAGG in a Sub-Select with ORDER BY gives error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

Using Oracle 19c:

I have the following query in which a Sub-Select (linked to the main Select via `plans1_.ID`) uses the `JSON_ARRAYAGG` function.

```
select
    ... , /* Other columns... */
    (SELECT
        json_arrayagg(json_object('sentDate' value mh.sent_date,
                                  'sentByEmail' value mh.send_by_email,    
                                  'sentBy' value mh.sent_by,
                                  'sentByName' value mh.sent_by_name,
                                  'sentToEmail' value mh.sendee_email) RETURNING CLOB) 
        from mail_history_t mh 
        where mh.plan_id = plans1_.id and mh.is_current_status = 'Y' 
        /*---This is the problem block: If I remove this ORDER BY the query works---*/
        order by mh.sent_date desc 
    ) as col_33_0_, 
    /* ... */

    from TABLE_T table0_ 
    left outer join PLANS_T plans1_ 
        on table0_.SOME_ID=plans1_.SOME_ID
    where ... /* etc. */
```

When I have the `order by` as part of my `select from mail_history_t mh`, I get the error

```
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
```

But when I get rid of the `order by` clause, the query works. Also, the Sub-Select works by itself if I were to isolate it.

My goal is to obtain the JSON-Array representation of the rows with columns that satisfy the condition, but sorted by `sent_date` DESC.

Comment: Don't put order by in a subquery.  That is not allowed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`JSON_ARRAYAGG()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_ARRAYAGG.html#GUID-6D56077D-78DE-4CC0-9498-225DDC42E054) accepts its own `ORDER BY` clause:

```
json_arrayagg(json_object('sentDate' value mh.sent_date,
                          'sentByEmail' value mh.send_by_email,    
                          'sentBy' value mh.sent_by,
                          'sentByName' value mh.sent_by_name,
                          'sentToEmail' value mh.sendee_email
                         ) ORDER BY mh.sent_date desc RETURNING CLOB
              )
```

`ORDER BY` in subqueries is not recommended.

Comment: any idea how to sort values on `json_objectagg` ?as it seems it does not support `order by` clause.